# How to access the virtual repo in artifactory

Tags: authentication, docker, artifactory

I created a virtual repository that combines the local docker repository for our internal use and the public docker registry. How do I use this virtual repository to docker pull images?

Here is the documentation I am reading https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories

I did not find the url that should be used to access these repos.

Comment: Did you read the [doc](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-VirtualDockerRepositories)?

Comment: yes, added to the ques

Comment: The url is like accessing any other repo in artifactory -> only with the virtual repo's name, e.g `/artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual`

Comment: does this also need to be configured in the reverse proxy?

Comment: yes, a virtual repo behaves just like any other repo externally